# build error - expected primary-expression before '.' token

Tags: c++, makefile, build

I am trying to run the make command on this program [here](https://github.com/Santy-8128/m3vcftools) but I am running into an error that might be related to C++. The error comes up as below:

```
make
[  7%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/m3vcftools.dir/src/Main.cpp.o
/hpc/home/lsiwzyj/programs/m3vcftools/src/Main.cpp:26: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
/hpc/home/lsiwzyj/programs/m3vcftools/src/Main.cpp:27: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
/hpc/home/lsiwzyj/programs/m3vcftools/src/Main.cpp:28: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
/hpc/home/lsiwzyj/programs/m3vcftools/src/Main.cpp:31: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
/hpc/home/lsiwzyj/programs/m3vcftools/src/Main.cpp:32: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
/hpc/home/lsiwzyj/programs/m3vcftools/src/Main.cpp:33: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
/hpc/home/lsiwzyj/programs/m3vcftools/src/Main.cpp:35: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
/hpc/home/lsiwzyj/programs/m3vcftools/src/Main.cpp:36: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
/hpc/home/lsiwzyj/programs/m3vcftools/src/Main.cpp:37: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
/hpc/home/lsiwzyj/programs/m3vcftools/src/Main.cpp:39: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
/hpc/home/lsiwzyj/programs/m3vcftools/src/Main.cpp:40: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
/hpc/home/lsiwzyj/programs/m3vcftools/src/Main.cpp:41: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
/hpc/home/lsiwzyj/programs/m3vcftools/src/Main.cpp:43: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
/hpc/home/lsiwzyj/programs/m3vcftools/src/Main.cpp:44: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
/hpc/home/lsiwzyj/programs/m3vcftools/src/Main.cpp:45: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/m3vcftools.dir/src/Main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/m3vcftools.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Here is a snippet of the related lines in main.cpp:

```
static void usage(FILE *fp);
//const char* createCommandLine(convert_args_t *args, const char *optionName); 
int main_m3vcfconcat(int argc, char *argv[]);
int main_m3vcfcompress(int argc, char *argv[]);
int main_m3vcfconvert(int argc, char *argv[]);


typedef struct
{
    int (*func)(int, char*[]);
    const char *alias, *help;
}
cmd_t;

static cmd_t cmds[] =
{
    { .func  = NULL,
      .alias = "M3VCF manipulation",
      .help  = NULL
    },

    { .func  = main_m3vcfcompress, //main_vcfannotate,
      .alias = "compress",
      .help  = "compress VCF file to M3VCF",
    },
    { .func  = main_m3vcfconcat, //main_vcfconcat,
      .alias = "concat",
      .help  = "concatenate M3VCF files from the same set of samples"
    },
    { .func  = main_m3vcfconvert, //main_vcfconvert,
      .alias = "convert",
      .help  = "convert M3VCF files to different formats and back"
    },
    { .func  = NULL,
      .alias = NULL,
      .help  = NULL
    }

};
```

I am apprehensive about changing any lines in Main.cpp though, and I am not familiar with C++. Do you have any idea how I can fix this? Thanks.

Comment: This seem to be a C program.

Comment: Such struct member initializations, as: `.func  = NULL`, were only added in C++20. Are you compiling with it enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of designators to initialise structures has a feature of `C` for quite a while, but only found its way into `C++` as of the `C++20` iteration.

Hence you need to ensure you *have* a compiler capable of handling `C++20`.

Depending on which toolchain you use, you may need specific versions, such as:

- gcc 8+, with`--std=c++20` for gcc10, `--std=c++2a` for gcc 8/9;
- clang 10+, with `--std=c++20`;
- Microsoft VS2019 16.1+, with `/std:c++latest` or `/std:c++20` (eventually).

Given the error you're getting, I suspect you either *don't* have such a beast, or there's something wrong with the way it's configured (such as incorrect standard specification).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. A quick check shows that the gcc version is 4.4.7, while clang might not even be installed. The server is definitely quite old, and I do not have sudo access. Am I out of luck at this point..?

Comment: @Jared, there are ways to install `gcc` or `clang` as a regular user. You probably won't be able to install it to places like`/usr/bin` but there's nothing stopping you from putting it under your home directory somewhere. I vaguely remember doing something similar many moons ago, though you may want to consider doing `clang` so as to not interfere with your system compiler.

Comment: thanks, i'll have a go at installing clang locally. I am looking to get the pre built binaries as clang also requires an updated gcc. Would you know which one I should get from the LLVM 10.0.0 list here? https://releases.llvm.org/download.html#3.0 The server I'm on uses CentOS release 6.10.